# Apache Nifi and connecting to local database on wamp server is not finding the database

Tags: localhost, apache-nifi

I am trying to connect to my local phpmyadmin database using the following url:

> jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=mydb_name

And using the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar` connector after [reading this post saying that](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/how-to-configure-and-connect-mysql-with-nifi-and-perform/td-p/109478) changing the connector version from `8` to `5.1.48` solved his problem.

I've downloaded the connector and saved it into `nifi1.10` lib directory and pointed the driver to its url:

> file:///Users/myuser/Desktop/nifi-1.10.0-bin/nifi-1.10.0/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.48-bin.jar

At the Nifi, I've created a new processor having `QueryDatabaseTableRecord` as main role and added the previous info to its properties:

[image]

AND the controller set as MySQL:

[image]

The final architecture is like so:

[image]

I am getting the following error:

> cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unknown database
>   phpmyadmin/db_structure.php)

[image]

Note that the wamp server is already running. Is it because of the url ? Because it is working when I paste it into the browser and it took me directly into the related database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read how to build jdbc url

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html

You have the error `unknown database ...`

Means that you specified database name incorrectly.

Instead of

> jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/db_structure.php?server=1&db=mydb_name

Use

```
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/mydb_name
```

Check that `mydb_name` is a valid database name.

Comment: Let me check it and gets back to you